# Ustring error (during printing)

Tags: c++, utf-8, glib, wofstream, glibmm

I want to parse UTF-8 file to ustring, I read this file in str. 
There is an error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Glib::ConvertError'.
What should I do?

```
char* cs = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * str.length());
strcpy(cs, str.c_str());
ustring res;
while (strlen(cs) > 0) {
    gunichar ch = g_utf8_get_char(cs);
    res.push_back(ch);
    cs = g_utf8_next_char(cs);
}
wofstream wout("output");
cout << res << endl;
```

Comment: According to this page: https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/2.34/classGlib_1_1ConvertError.html the converterror contains some extra information about "what is wrong", which may be helpful in determining what is the ACTUAL cause of error.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very wrong:

```
char* cs = (char*) malloc(sizeof(str.c_str()));
```

as `sizeof(str.c_str())` is bound to give you some small number like 4 or 8 (whichever is the size of a pointer on your machine, as the result of `str.c_str()`.

Of course, it doesn't REALLY matter, since the next line, you are leaking the memory you just allocated incorrectly:

```
cs = const_cast<char*> (str.c_str());
```

I'm far from convinced that you need the `const_cast<char *>` (it is certainly WRONG to do this, since modifying the string inside a `string` is undefined behaviour).